# Grails findBy is not working with combination of Or/And Condition

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0, shiro, grails-domain-class

I am working with Grails application. I am using Apache Shiro security plugin for my grails application. I am trying to use `findBy` query on my `User` domain class with **Or** and **And** condition but it gives me an error.

**My Domain Class**

```
class ShiroUser {
      String firstName
      String lastName
      String username
      String email
      String passwordHash
      String userStatus

      static hasMany = [ roles: ShiroRole, permissions: String ]

      static constraints = {
          username(nullable: false, blank: false, unique: true)
          email(nullable: false, blank: false, email: true,unique: true)
     }}
```

I have executed following query:

```
ShiroUser.findByUsernameOrEmailAndUserStatus(params?.username,params?.username,'Active')
```

I get following error:

```
Message: No property found for name [usernameOrEmail] for class [class com.chatportal.ShiroUser]
```

But If I execute query with only **Or** condition then it works fine.

```
ShiroUser.findByUsernameOrEmail(params?.username,params?.username)
```

Anyone please help me that what is wrong with my condition when I used **Or** and **And** condition with findBy ?

Answer (score 5):

["You can combine as many criteria as you like, but they must all be combined with And or all Or. If you need to combine And and Or or if the number of criteria creates a very long method name, just convert the query to a Criteria or HQL query."](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.x/guide/single.html#finders)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I Know the Criteria or HQL query but I want to achieve it by findBy********

Comment: It wasn't a suggestion, it was a link to the docs showing you that you cannot do what you want with dynamic finders. Originally you could only have one or two attributes with either one `And` or one `Or`. When that restriction was removed it was decided that you could only use all `And` or all `Or` because there's no way to group or use parentheses. If you need more complex queries, use a different query approach.